# Lie Bracket and Taylor series

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

[image]

So this is from Kirillov's notes on Lie Groups. What I don't understand is the last paragraph. It seems that the proof isn't complete, or at the very least I don't see how he gets the conclusion that $\lambda(x,x)=0$.

Comment: I presume $\mu(x,y)=\ln(\exp(x)\exp(y))$, in which case $\mu(x,x)=2x$ is immediate.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I have updated the picture to include this information.

Comment: That part I know. But why do the higher order terms vanish?

Comment: That's the assertion I don't get. Because by cancelling the $2x$ from both sides I don't see why the higher order terms vanish.

Comment: Oh I think I see how he gets it. I think he uses the fact that Taylor series expansions are unique, hence the higher order terms must vanish.

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Great! Thanks anon.